# NSTextField with NSFormatter results in broken continuous binding

Tags: macos, cocoa, validation, binding, nsformatter

I have a textfield which has to be unique so I added my custom `NSFormatter` (see below)

The formatter works, as you can see on the screenshot, but the continuous binding, which I am using is broken, so for example the bound text does no longer get updated in real-time.

I found a possible cause [here](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/184885-nsformatter-interfering-with-bindings-continuous-update.html), but I don't know how to work around this problem and re-enable the continuous binding:

> ...
>
> - **12.** If the view has an NSFormatter attached to it, the value is
>     formatted by the NSFormatter instance. Proceed to Step 17.
> - ...
> - **17.** The updated value is displayed in the user interface.
>
> So it looks like it's intentionally skipping the steps we want. This
>   is very annoying. I tried NSValueTransformer, but adding that to an
>   editable NSTextField makes it non-editable.

#### My formatter

```
- (BOOL)getObjectValue:(out id *)obj forString:(NSString *)string errorDescription:(out NSString **)error {

    if([string isNotEqualTo:@"todo-invalid-value"]){
        *obj = string;
        NSLog(@"YES");
        return YES;
    } else {
        if(error){
            *error = @"ERROR: not allowed";
        }
        return NO;
    }
}

- (NSString *)stringForObjectValue:(id)obj {
    return (NSString *)obj;
}
```

#### Working validation

[image]

Please note that the title of the list item should be updated with the text, that I entered in the textfield.

Comment: did you try programmatically?

Comment: @hussainShabbir You mean setup the bindings programmatically? I did not try that, but I would prefer to keep the bindings in IB.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same problem over the weekend, and eventually discovered a [post from 2008 by Yann Disser](http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2008/May/msg00083.html) on the cocoa-dev mailing list which shed some light on my problem.

I had an existing `NSFormatter` that was working fine and when I broke down the components, so I spent a little more time on it this morning and located Yann's post.

The key is that you need to return a different object than the one that is passed in.  It's subtle, but the docs say: If conversion is successful, upon return contains the object *created from string*.

The problem I was having stemmed from the fact that the `NSString` that was coming in was actually an `NSMutableString` and was getting modified later.

Here's the code modified to return `[NSString stringWithString: string]`, which should fix your problem:

```
- (BOOL)getObjectValue:(out id *)obj forString:(NSString *)string errorDescription:(out NSString **)error {

    if([string isNotEqualTo:@"todo-invalid-value"]){
        *obj = [NSString stringWithString: string];
        NSLog(@"YES");
        return YES;
    } else {
        if(error){
            *error = @"ERROR: not allowed";
        }
        return NO;
    }
}
```